# can not install nestjs app to hosting with cpanel

Tags: node.js, npm, hosting, nestjs, cpanel

I have project with nestjs, and I am unable to install it to hosting,
got this error:

returncode: 1

stdout:

start-project@0.0.1 start:prod /home/enebbvmz/server/dist

node main.js

stderr:

/home/enebbvmz/nodevenv/server/dist/12/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

[31m[Nest] 58145   - [39m06/10/2021, 7:13:28 PM   [38;5;3m[PackageLoader] [39m[31mNo driver (HTTP) has been selected. In order to take advantage of the default driver, please, ensure to install the "@nestjs/platform-express" package ($ npm install @nestjs/platform-express).
[39m

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! start-project@0.0.1 start:prod: `node main.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the start-project@0.0.1 start:prod script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/enebbvmz/.npm/_logs/2021-06-10T15_13_28_703Z-debug.log

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop you app.
Your Application Root should be just `server`.
Aplication startup file should be `dist/main.js`.

Then you can click on `Save Button`, restart your app and click on `Run Npm Install` and will work.

I recommend you create a subdomain for backend, then you can use your main domain for your frontend app.